# Network accessing rules between AKS and ACR

Tags: azure, kubernetes

I created a new resource group with AKS and ACR instances.

- ACR: not associated with any vnet

  - network rule: deny all by default
  - bypass MS trusted services
- AKS: not associated with any vnet

  - has a `SystemAssigned` identity
- AcrPull role assignment between AKS and ACR

I am able to access both resources locally, but the AKS instance cannot access the ACR. After playing with the settings for a while, I found the AKS can access the ACR if:

- ACR network rule is set to allow all by default
- ACR network rule white list some `20.53.198.0/24` IP range

According to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/allow-access-trusted-services), AKS is *not* a trusted service. But the AKS nodes' IP is not something you can control.

So, my question is, what is the right way to set the ACR network rule to make sure only

- AKS
- whitelisted IP

can access it?

### Update

After some research, I found I have to create a *Private Endpoint* to connect the AKS and the ACR.

Another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71537984/private-endpoint-between-aks-and-acr/71578489?noredirect=1#comment126645180_71578489) about the same topic, but using Terraform to implement it.

Comment: "AKS: not associated with any vnet" <-- this cannot be true ;) AKS will always be sitting in some VNet. You should allow traffic from that VNet to your ACR and it should work.

Comment: Can you point me to some references? I could not see any vnet resource in my RG.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/concepts-network#azure-virtual-networks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You [**David S**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/309830/david-s) for your update. Posting your suggestion as an answer to help other community members if they encounter same requirement.

**You need a private endpoint to make a connection between the AKS and  ACR.**

> By default, ACR is public. Here want to disable its public FQDN and
> make it accessible only using Private Endpoint (aka PE). Private
> Endpoint will create a private IP address in a Subnet/VNET.
> Documentation about private ACR is here.
>
> Private Endpoint will disable NSGs on its host Subnet. We don’t want
> this to happen to AKS Subnet, so we can create another Subnet in AKS
> VNET dedicated for Private Endpoints.

Would suggest to follow this *[*tutorial*](https://This%20tutorial%20will%20provide%20a%20guidance%20to%20setup%20a%20private%20environment%20for%20AKS%20and%20ACR%20with%20only%20access%20from%20an%20Azure%20VM.%20We%20will%20leverage%20Azure%20Private%20Link%20with%20Private%20Endpoint%20to%20get%20access%20to%20these%20resources.)*, will provide a guidance to setup a private environment for AKS and ACR with only access from an Azure VM and make connection between AKS and ACR.

**Note : Just Ingore the connection of VM for the AKS and ACR only focus on build the connection for ACR and AKS as provided in above tutorial in part 2 and point number 1 and 3**

You can also refer this [*document*](https://azureossd.github.io/2021/01/28/aks-acr-private/) Deploying and setting the private link betweeen Azure Kubernetes Service and Azure Container Registry with public endpoint disabled