# Private Endpoint between AKS and ACR

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-aks, terraform-provider-azure

I want to create AKS and ACR resources in my Azure environment. The script is able to create the two resources, and I am able to connect to each of them. But the AKS node cannot pull images from the ACR. After some research, I found I need to create a Private Endpoint between the AKS and ACR.

The strange thing is that if I create the PE using Terraform the AKS and ACR still cannot communicate. If I create the PE manually, they can communicate. I compared the parameters of the two PEs on the UI and they look the same.

Could someone help me define the PE using the following script? Or let me know what I did wrong?

Thanks!

## Full TF script without the Private Endpoint

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "=2.97.0"
    }
  }

  required_version = ">= 1.1.7"
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}

  subscription_id = "xxx"
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = "aks-rg"
  location = "East US"
}

resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks" {
  name                = "my-aks"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  dns_prefix          = "myaks"

  default_node_pool {
    name       = "default"
    node_count = 2
    vm_size    = "Standard_B2s"
  }

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_container_registry" "acr" {
  name                = "my-aks-acr-123"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  sku                 = "Premium"
  admin_enabled       = true

  network_rule_set {
    default_action = "Deny"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "acrpull" {
  principal_id                     = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.kubelet_identity[0].object_id
  role_definition_name             = "AcrPull"
  scope                            = azurerm_container_registry.acr.id
  skip_service_principal_aad_check = true
}
```

Comment: Can you list your tf code used to provision PEs? Couple of things which strike me are `Target Sub Resource` & `integration with private dns zone`..

Comment: When I create the PE, I struggled to figure out how to connect AKS and ACR using the PE. It is easy to do on the UI, but I could not find out what properties do I need in TF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Then you need to create a VNET, a Subnet (no part of this code ) plus a private DNS zone:

Private DNS zone:

```
resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone" "example" {
  name                = "mydomain.com"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}
```

AKS Part:

```
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks" {
  name                = "my-aks"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  dns_prefix          = "myaks"
  private_cluster_enabled   = true

  default_node_pool {
    name       = "default"
    node_count = 2
    vm_size    = "Standard_B2s"
  }

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
}
```

You need to create the ACR and a private endpoint for the ACR:

```
resource "azurerm_container_registry" "acr" {
  name                = "my-aks-acr-123"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  public_network_access_enabled = false
  sku                 = "Premium"
  admin_enabled       = true
}

resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "acr" {
  name                = "pvep-acr"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  subnet_id           = YOUR_SUBNET

  private_service_connection {
    name                           = "example-acr"
    private_connection_resource_id = azurerm_container_registry.acr.id
    is_manual_connection           = false
    subresource_names              = ["registry"]
  }

  private_dns_zone_group {
    name                 = data.azurerm_private_dns_zone.example.name
    private_dns_zone_ids = [data.azurerm_private_dns_zone.example.id]
  }
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "acrpull" {
  principal_id                     = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.kubelet_identity[0].object_id
  role_definition_name             = "AcrPull"
  scope                            = azurerm_container_registry.acr.id
  skip_service_principal_aad_check = true
}
```

Comment: yes, I want to create a private AKS and it can only pull from my private ACR

Comment: i updated above code for you use case